# Is there some php_info-like method in ruby?

Tags: ruby, sinatra, php

Is there some method to show Session, ENV, POST, and GET data in a Ruby web app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly not like php_info , but you can get :

1) On console run command : **rake about**

2) `http://localhost:3001/rails/info/properties` => only on localhost

3) embedded erb might be helpful...

```
<%= params.inspect %>

<%= session.inspect %>
```

Comment: I do not use rails, only sinatra. This is not exactly what I mean.

Comment: I think it should be specified in question . Else not much idea about sinatra . I think SINATRA has request.env , so you get those information with this variable.

Comment: Yes. Information is on the variable. But the question is about a method to display it in a phpinfo-like style.

Comment: Accepted as correct since the erb/haml method seems the only one available directly on sinatra. Thanks!